# String to number conversion

Tags: string, lua, numbers

I am trying to make several chatcommands in my new server modification for Crysis Wars that requires numbers and strings. To get the player input, I do this:

```
local name, time, reason = string.match(chatMsg, "^!punish (.*) (%d+) (.*)");
```

For some reason, it's not working properly (gets the number value as a string). The number value is the second variable in the string.match. Am I doing something wrong here?
I've also tried to find a solution to this, but have not found any. Perhaps I should be using a different method to get the number?

Comment: this could not work, as `tonumber` takes (up to) two arguments, and the second must be a number type, while `string.match` returns as many *string* values as captures in the pattern; Like I wrote in my answer, **add** the line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually quite simple, just add the following line after the line you posted in your question.

```
time = tonumber(time);
```

As mentioned in the comments below, you can achieve the same with

```
time = time + 0
```

Comment: Lua *does* do automatic conversion if you do arithmetic on decimal strings.  e.g. `"42"+"5"` gives (the number) 47.

Comment: Ouch, I stand corrected. It seems it does. Well the answer is still correct in that this will convert the string value to a number *cough*

Comment: Agree with @finnw :  `time = time + 0` would do the same conversion  ;-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff There is one difference though: `"a"+0` causes an error while  `tonumber("a")` just returns `nil`